# How to assign "/" to a variable in shell scripting

Tags: shell

Hi guys I am trying to write a shell script which installs java and sets the paths for it.

For this I was trying to get the root folder where I have installed Java. I successfully did so by using grep command. My java home directory is like this `/usr/bin/java`. I obtained `usr` directory separately. Now I want to add `/usr` string literal to a variable. But it's just adding `usr` with a white space before it.. Can anyone help me out with this.

Here is the example I'm giving not the real one though...

```
directory="/usr/bin/java"
echo $directory
IFS=/
set $directory
echo /$2
t=$'/'$2
echo $t
```

Comment: Try to escape the forward slash; `\/`

Comment: Tell us what shell your are using, that could help in getting an answer

Comment: Restore `IFS`! Or better: don't play with `IFS`, use simply: `set -- ${directory//\// }`

Answer (score 1):

Under [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), you could simply:

```
directory="/usr/bin/java"
set -- ${directory//\// }
echo /$3
```

will print:

```
/java
```

Comment: I dont want to just simply print... i want to store it in a varibale as well @F.Hauri